# Best practices for showing an error

Tags: ios

A part of my app makes a POST request to a web service. I have it working but now I am in the "lets see how we can break it" phase. I have discovered that if the user does not have a network connection (cell/wifi) then the POST didFailWithError and essentially just sits there with no indication of passing or failing. I know how I can handle the error (as in where to put the code) but I am wondering what would be the best thing to do? Should I set an alert such as "Please check your internet connection". Also should I make it a full popup or should I just have a label that I set text to?

This is my first time making an App that will actually be used so any other advice as far as alerting the user and best practices with that I'd love to hear.

Comment: To give some more information, This particular event is after the user enters text into a field and pushes a button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mostly up to you, as either method would be fine. If the action is something the user actively interacts with (e.g., presses a button prior to it occurring), an alert would probably be best. Otherwise, if the action happens in the background or with little user interaction, I would recommend using a label or some other visual cue. Often, in apps that have a feed you'll see a UIView appear above/below the feed saying "network unavailable" or similar.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense. I decided to go with a UIAlertView because it is after the user enters in their phone number and presses a button. Thank you for the advice as well!

Comment: I agree, based on your edit. A more direct error is best in your situation. Good luck with the app :)

Comment: Thanks for confirming and for the good luck! I am really excited and hoping it all goes great!